# Set image SRC using GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I have a TIFF image with no coordinate reference system and I need that image to be in EPSG 32631. Is there a way to do this using GDAL?

Note: I am very new to Python

Comment: Does your TIFF file have a world file (.tfw)?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `osr.SpatialReference()` object and then use it to set the raster projection using `gdal`. If you have `gdal` installed you'll have `osr` already. Here is an example:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr

# create spatial reference object using your EPSG
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(32631)

# open your raster and set projection
ds = gdal.Open(r'C:\path\to\your_raster.tif', 1)  # the second argument (1) opens the raster in update mode
ds.SetProjection(sr.ExportToWkt())  # this method takes a string rather than an object

# save changes
del ds
```

Comment: thank you for your answers, i run the code but nothing really changed. when you use del ds the image SRC should be already changed?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run the code? How are you checking that the image has an SRC? Are you running the code while opening the raster using other program?

Comment: no i do not get any errors. I took the same image and plug it in QGIS to see if the SRC changed, but nothing changed. Should i do something different ?

Comment: Can you upload the image somewhere? Also, do you know if the image is georeferenced? One possibility is that it is not georeferenced but you should still see the image SRC when you check its properties in QGIS.